# Modern SGML Viewer

Tags: viewer, sgml

I was provided some documentation in SGML format. Not being familiar with the format I searched the web to find a suitable viewer but cant seem to locate one. Is there such a thing as a modern SGML viewer?

Comment: SGML is plain text. Can't you just use a text editor?

Comment: It has graphic elements and some formatting.

Comment: SGML is still used, but it's mostly superseded by XML these days (though in a sense XML *is* SGML: XML is a subset of full SGML). There are powerful editors that can handle both SGML and XML (example: http://www.ptc.com/product/arbortext/editor/), including showing images and using stylesheets. But I would be surprised if there were any "modern SGML viewers".

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an SGML viewer, because SGML is not a "document format" (or "document type") that could be visually displayed.

SGML is a language that is used to *describe* a document type.

You need to look for a "viewer" for your specific document type, and not for SGML.

#### SGML document types

You need to find out which document type your SGML file uses, and then find a viewer for that document type. You can see which document type your SGML file uses at the very top of the SGML file, where it says `<!DOCTYPE ...`. E.g for a file that uses the document type XHTML it looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" []>
```

Document types described using SGML might be:

- [ATA iSpec 2200 AMM](https://www.webxsystems.com/products/stylesheets/ata-ispec-2200-amm)
- CMM (Component Maintenance Manual)
- [HTML4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html)
- ...

(SGML document types are described by ["document type definitions" (DTD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition).)

#### Viewers / Editors

Of course, for HTML the "viewer" would be a web browser.

For other formats, the "viewer" (or "editor") will often be some kind of custom software, such as [Arbortext Editor](https://www.ptc.com/de/products/arbortext#datasheets) with custom extensions, or custom scripts or software that converts this specific document type into e.g. PDF. There is usually some kind of "styling file" involved, like [CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS) or [FOSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formatting_Output_Specification_Instance), which describes how each element should be formatted and layouted.

Sometimes, the SGML files are not meant to be displayed as a whole at all, but are used to store data or transfer data between data bases and other software, which might only display small portions of the data at once.